# HTML stop button won't stop with $id

Tags: php, html

I made a stop button and a renew button.
Renew button works fine, but the `stopBtn` won't work, it just reloads the page. I've spent few hours trying other ways of methods and it just refreshes the page. If someone could shed some light on where I went wrong would be great.

```
if (isset($_POST['stopBtn'])) {
    $attackID = intval($_POST['id']);

    $SQLSelect = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `id` = :id AND `stopped` = '0' LIMIT 1");
    $SQLSelect->execute([':id' => $attackID]);
    while ($show = $SQLSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $host = $show['ip'];
        $port = $show['port'];
        $time = $show['time'];
        $username1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $methodcheck = $show['method'];

        $odb->query("UPDATE `logs` SET `stopped` = '1' WHERE `id` = '".$attackID."'");
    }
}
```

As you can see below my button code is in check.

```
<td class=""><form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="stopCheck" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($logs['id']); ?>">
    <input <?php if (time() > $expires or htmlspecialchars($logs['stopped']) == 1) {
        echo 'type="submit" name="attackBtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" value="Renew Attack"';
    } else {
        echo 'type="submit" name="stopBtn" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" value="Stop Attack"';
    } ?>>
</form></td>
```

Comment: Why did you concatenate your SQL like this `'".$attackID."'"`? Every query must be prepared!

Comment: What is the purpose of `htmlspecialchars($logs['stopped']) == 1`?

Comment: 0 = not stopped 1 = stopped and can be renewed.

Comment: No, I meant why call `htmlspecialchars` on it?

Comment: Two suggestions - for a test, just generate both buttons statically. Then, give the form a clear 'action', i.e. the current page name.

Comment: Your hidden field is named `stopCheck`, but you look for `intval($_POST['id'])`. Is that a mistake?

Comment: I tried correcting no luck still

Comment: i use htmlspecialschars alot to make sure nothing is left unfiltered and XSS can't be performed :D

Comment: Yes, but it makes sense when you output it to the browser. In the if statement in makes no sense.

Comment: Still no luck it just reloads so the button isn't grabbing the id